# How does a Email-Form work?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

this might be a stupid question but its been bugging me all day, I am creating a website from scratch in html , css and js and hope for it to go live very soon. Almost at the end section which is producing a email form for users to enter on the site and the information gets sent directly to my email address. I tried doing alot of research and noticed that like all email forms are done in php if this is the case I may have to do it in a different system because my XAMPP is not working and I won't go into that now but is there any other way to produce a email form without the use of php and still have the sending functionality? Also if produced in php and website goes live will the php code for the email form work as it will be developed in a local host ? Sorry about this question I have never set put up a scratch website live only done wordpress.

Comment: if not php, then some other serverside language is required

Comment: Will ASP.NET MVC work?

Comment: Just about any language should work. If it doesn't have a mail library, you can always pipe to a shell command that executes `sendmail`.

Comment: What do you mean by "my XAMPP is not working"? You can't use the server at all, or just the PHP part doesn't work? You're going to have a hard time creating a useful website if XAMPP isn't working.

Comment: What code have you tried that's not working?  Showing that will go a long way to getting a good answer here.

Comment: @Barmer It was showing a error in APACHE sorry not XAMPP so I changed the ports and now when I run a php code in the url with local host it just shows a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

E-mail can't be sent client-side (in browser).  There are `mailto:` links you can make which suggest to the browser to open up the configured program for handling mail, but these don't offer a facility for handling the form data and creating an e-mail from it.

E-mail forms are like all other forms.  You create a `<form>` and set its `action` attribute to a URL that will handle the form data.  When the form is filled out and the submit button is pressed, your browser makes an HTTP request to the URL from the `action` attribute, with all the data from the form.  That's all the browser knows and cares about.

Now, server-side, you can handle this data however you like.  PHP is a popular server-side language, and you can write code to send e-mails.  You don't have to use PHP though... you can use anything you want.  The browser doesn't know or care what happens server side.

If you don't want to host this functionality, there are several mail providers that will do it for you.  Many of them even have pre-built forms where the data is sent to the server via AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! what I mean is that the client send it to me from filling out the form in the website and I receive it directly in my email.